# Using uninitialized "redirecttoindex" variable

Tags: wordpress

Suddenly out of nowhere I can not log in into my WordPress site. The site is working but `wp-admin` is not. In the error log I get:

`2022/07/04 23:45:58 [warn] 31793#31793: *300658 using uninitialized "redirecttoindex" variable, client: ip.000.000.000, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/HTTP/2.0", host: "mydomain.com"`

How can I debug this? I have just got this site for maintenance and I am not very familiar with WordPress. Should I diff it with the original version and see if files are modified?

I scanned the code and there are no `redirecttoindex` variables. Is something up with nginx?

I also can not find anything on google with such a query.

```
Server API: FPM/FastCGI 
PHP Version 7.4.26
nginx/1.20.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confirm the other pages in the sites this working well ? If the answer is Yes, you need the check if exists some plugin what redirect the route of wp-admin for new route. First we have to activate the debug mode in the wordpress in the file wp_config find de const WP_DEBUG and set true.

P.S: Don´t activate the DEBUG in the product view.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you were right! There was a plugin that was hiding the default wp-admin path from the world; I was getting 403 error